# Склонение фамилии Комар

Tags: орфоэпия, склонение-фамилий

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно будет склоняться фамилия Комар (ударение на букву о)?

Answer (score 2):

> Если фамилия оканчивается на согласный (кроме фамилий на *-ых, -их*...), то здесь — и только здесь! — имеет значение пол носителя фамилии. **Все мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный, склоняются — это закон русской грамматики.** Все женские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный, не склоняются. При этом языковое происхождение фамилии не имеет значения. Склоняются в том числе и мужские фамилии, совпадающие с нарицательными существительными.

Ко́мар, По́вар или Кома́р — нет разницы, склоняем по общим правилам:

И. п. — Ко́мар, По́вар, Кома́р;
Р. п. — Ко́мара, По́вара, Комара́;
Д. п. — Ко́мару, По́вару, Комару́;
В. п. — Ко́мара, По́вара, Комара́;
Т. п. — Ко́маром, По́варом, Комаро́м;
П. п. — о Ко́маре, о По́варе, о Комаре́.

[Склонение фамилий](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/#:%7E:text=%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0,%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8.)